# why android studio logcat don't show crashes error?

Tags: android, android-logcat

i am having a problem that when i run app on android studio it don't show any crashes error in the logcat.. i tried by restarting logcat but did't work for me..i have searched a lot about it but unable to resolve this issue.can anyone   please help me?

```
    -26 19:47:39.936  27780-27780/dictor.win.com.windictor V/ActivityThread﹕ Resuming ActivityRecord{7d2b2fa token=android.os.BinderProxy@2e9a90ab {dictor.win.com.windictor/dictor.win.com.windictor.Splash}} with isForward=true
03-26 19:47:39.936  27780-27780/dictor.win.com.windictor V/ActivityThread﹕ Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{7d2b2fa token=android.os.BinderProxy@2e9a90ab {dictor.win.com.windictor/dictor.win.com.windictor.Splash}}
03-26 19:47:39.937  27780-27780/dictor.win.com.windictor D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{7d2b2fa token=android.os.BinderProxy@2e9a90ab {dictor.win.com.windictor/dictor.win.com.windictor.Splash}}
03-26 19:47:42.894  27780-27780/dictor.win.com.windictor D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{7d2b2fa token=android.os.BinderProxy@2e9a90ab {dictor.win.com.windictor/dictor.win.com.windictor.Splash}}
03-26 19:47:42.908  27780-27780/dictor.win.com.windictor D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@2e9a90ab
03-26 19:47:42.909  27780-27780/dictor.win.com.windictor V/ActivityThread﹕ Handling launch of ActivityRecord{34610d7c token=android.os.BinderProxy@956b605 {dictor.win.com.windictor/dictor.win.com.windictor.SignIn}}
03-26 19:47:42.910  27780-27780/dictor.win.com.windictor V/ActivityThread﹕ ActivityRecord{34610d7c token=android.os.BinderProxy@956b605 {dictor.win.com.windictor/dictor.win.com.windictor.SignIn}}: app=android.app.Application@e7e4aa1, appName=dictor.win.com.windictor, pkg=dictor.win.com.windictor, comp={dictor.win.com.windictor/dictor.win.com.windictor.SignIn}, dir=/data/app/dictor.win.com.windictor-1/base.apk
03-26 19:47:43.005  27780-27780/dictor.win.com.windictor V/ActivityThread﹕ Performing resume of ActivityRecord{34610d7c token=android.os.BinderProxy@956b605 {dictor.win.com.windictor/dictor.win.com.windictor.SignIn}}
03-26 19:47:43.005  27780-27780/dictor.win.com.windictor D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{34610d7c token=android.os.BinderProxy@956b605 {dictor.win.com.windictor/dictor.win.com.windictor.SignIn}}
03-26 19:47:43.005  27780-27780/dictor.win.com.windictor V/ActivityThread﹕ Resume ActivityRecord{34610d7c token=android.os.BinderProxy@956b605 {dictor.win.com.windictor/dictor.win.com.windictor.SignIn}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false
03-26 19:47:43.009  27780-27780/dictor.win.com.windictor V/ActivityThread﹕ Resuming ActivityRecord{34610d7c token=android.os.BinderProxy@956b605 {dictor.win.com.windictor/dictor.win.com.windictor.SignIn}} with isForward=true
03-26 19:47:43.009  27780-27780/dictor.win.com.windictor V/ActivityThread﹕ Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{34610d7c token=android.os.BinderProxy@956b605 {dictor.win.com.windictor/dictor.win.com.windictor.SignIn}}
03-26 19:47:43.010  27780-27780/dictor.win.com.windictor D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{34610d7c token=android.os.BinderProxy@956b605 {dictor.win.com.windictor/dictor.win.com.windictor.SignIn}}
03-26 19:47:43.594  27780-27780/dictor.win.com.windictor D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@2e9a90ab
03-26 19:47:45.878  27780-27780/dictor.win.com.windictor V/TextView﹕ stopSelectionActionMode()
03-26 19:47:48.552  27780-27780/dictor.win.com.windictor D/ActivityThread﹕ hoder:android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder@b16f3ef,provider,holder.Provider:android.content.ContentProviderProxy@10f2defc
```

Comment: Search yours logs for `FATAL`.

Comment: it shows nothing in the logs

Comment: Maybe check if the right process and device are chosen..